# Why is it wrong to name 2-methyl-1-propanol (the preferred IUPAC name of isobutanol)1-methylpropanol?

Tags: nomenclature

Given the compound 2-methyl-1-propanol (isobutanol), the preferred IUPAC name is the aforementioned. But why is it wrong to name it 1-methylpropanol? Given that the methyl can't go to any other of the carbons, methylpropanol has a given structure with only the hydroxyl group changing. Can you point to literature backing up the claim that the 1-methylpropanol might be confused with 1-methyl-propanol? (meaning that the number denotes the carbon on which the methyl is)

Comment: 1-methyl _anything_ is an abomination.

Comment: Why so? Methylpropanol can only have two structures. I don't need to name the methyl because it can only go to the second carbon, right?

Comment: So you are suggesting that 1-methylpropanol defaults to 2-methyl-1-propanol because methylpropanol requires that the methyl be bound at the 2 position (as it otherwise would be butanol)? I would counterargue that it is better not to leave things to interpretation. Computers have enough to worry about.

Comment: @BuckThorn Yes, exactly. I suppose that this is the case. But is it really wrong?

Comment: Wrong in the sense that it runs against the conventions of chemical nomenclature, and requires an additional layer of interpretation to resolve the ambiguity associated with the meaning of "methylpropanol". If you go one more carbon (1-methylbutanol) you run into further ambiguity. I would invoke Occam's razor.

Answer (score 6):

According to the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001),* locants are placed
immediately in front of the part of the name to which they refer.

> **P-14.3.2** Position of locants
>
> Locants (numerals and/or letters) are placed immediately before that part of the name to which they relate, except in the case of the traditional contracted names when locants are
> placed at the front of their names.

Therefore, the preferred IUPAC name of “2-methyl-1-propanol” actually is **2-methylpropan-1-ol**.

For the same reason, the locant “1-” in the hypothetical name “1-methylpropanol” can only refer to the methyl group.

Furthermore, “1-methyl-propanol” is just a wrong spelling of the hypothetical name “1-methylpropanol”.

> I don't need to name the methyl because it can only go to the second carbon, right?

IUPAC nomenclature doesn’t work like that. Generally, the complete information about a structure is explicitly given by the name and does not rely on any implied information or hidden logic involving other structures.

The parent compound propan-1-ol has several different hydrogen atoms that could be substituted. Therefore, the locant cannot be omitted in substituted propan-1-ol, e.g. 1-chloropropan-1-ol, 2-chloropropan-1-ol or 3-chloropropan-1-ol.

This principle applies to any substituent. The special situation that replacing the chloro substituent in 1-chloropropan-1-ol with a methyl substituent would actually lead to the name butan-2-ol instead of 1-methylpropan-1-ol and that replacing the chloro substituent in 3-chloropropan-1-ol with a methyl substituent would actually lead to the name butan-1-ol instead of 3-methylpropan-1-ol does not change the preferred name for 2-methylpropan-1-ol.